# How do I avoid removing blocks of text between Regex flags in my text file using the the Python re library?

Tags: python, regex, sed

I am currently trying to use the Python `re` library to cut out blocks of text files based on unique flags I put inside of those files. However, if I include multiple instances of flagged blocks in my file, I find that all flagged blocks get lumped together as one big block and deleted.

Consider this example text file, call it `test.txt`:

```
Do, a deer, a female deer
### mark
Re, a drop of golden sun
### end mark
Mi, a name I call myself
Fa, a long long way to run
### mark
So, a needle pulling thread
La, a note to follow So
Ti, a drink with jam and bread
### end mark
Now that brings us back to Do
```

I'm using the following code to cut out the blocks of text I want:

```
def replace_file_text(path, regex, repl, flags=0):
    old_text = ""
    with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        old_text = f.read()
    new_text = re.sub(regex, repl, old_text, flags=flags)
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(new_text)

replace_file_text("test.txt", r"### mark.*### end mark", "", re.DOTALL)
```

What I want the text file to be converted to is:

```
Do, a deer, a female deer
Mi, a name I call myself
Fa, a long long way to run
Now that brings us back to Do
```

But what I actually end up getting is:

```
Do, a deer, a female deer
Now that brings us back to Do
```

I see what the problem is, but I'm not sure how to avoid counting instances of my flags as text to delete.

Originally, I had coded a shell script to cut out these blocks of text using the `sed` text editor, and it had worked pretty well:

```
sed "/### mark/,/### end mark/d" test.txt > new-test.txt
```

Can someone explain to me why the latter approach works while the former doesn't? And does anyone have any suggestions for a relatively clean way to avoid deleting the text between my flags in the Python version?

Comment: ` r"### mark.*?### end mark"` ?

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thank you Chris!

Comment: Glad to have helped. The `?` in this regex makes the preceding `.*` **nongreedy**. The regex first looks ahead to see if it matches `### end mark`. If not, it advances one position and keeps looking and advancing until it finds that phrase. Without the `non-greedy ?`, `.*` reads in all the characters in the string and then backtracks to find the last occurrence of the phase. `?` also has another use (depending on its placement). It will behave as `damonmickelsen` noted in his post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add some special characters to your regex expression. For example, the special character ?

> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

Currently, with no special characters it will be "greedy" and match the first and the last occurrence of the pattern. Check out the "Special Character" section of Python's "[re - Regular expression operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)" page.

I'm imagining you will end up with something to this effect:
`replace_file_text("test.txt", r"(### mark).*(### end mark)?", "", re.DOTALL)`

With regular expressions, I find that trial and error is how you find the right solution. They are complicated and particular.

Comment: As it turns out, all I needed was to add a question mark to the `.*` portion to form `r"### mark.*?### end mark"`. To put it in terms you used, that basically makes the match as non-greedy as possible, so that I match the small segments to each other rather than the whole thing. Thank you for your help, though!